# How can I convert data received from a URL call into NSString?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to make a simple url call. I cannot convert the bytes into NSString. Following is my code. I get this in my console message; data received from url: †F»∞

```
    -(void)buttonClicked{

 NSLog(@"Hello Login clicked...");
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
 request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/contact/"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setTimeoutInterval:60.0];

        NSError *error;
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"data received from url: %s", data);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `%s` modifier when logging.  That's for printing `char*` strings, which an `NSString` is most definitely *not*.  Use the `%@` modifier instead.  That's specifically for printing Objective-C objects (like an `NSString`).